# Get a JSON value from an array using Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude values from a JSON array - `$response`, returned from Google, from their Geocoding services.

The JSON array is returned as such (random address):

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"57",
               "short_name":"57",
               "types":[
                  "street_number"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Polo Gardens",
               "short_name":"Polo Gardens",
               "types":[
                  "route"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Bucksburn",
               "short_name":"Bucksburn",
               "types":[
                  "sublocality_level_1",
                  "sublocality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Aberdeen",
               "short_name":"Aberdeen",
               "types":[
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Aberdeen",
               "short_name":"Aberdeen",
               "types":[
                  "postal_town"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Aberdeen City",
               "short_name":"Aberdeen City",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United Kingdom",
               "short_name":"GB",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"AB21 9JU",
               "short_name":"AB21 9JU",
               "types":[
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"57 Polo Gardens, Aberdeen, Aberdeen City AB21 9JU, UK",
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":57.1912463,
               "lng":-2.1790257
            },
            "location_type":"ROOFTOP",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":57.19259528029149,
                  "lng":-2.177676719708498
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":57.18989731970849,
                  "lng":-2.180374680291502
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match":true,
         "place_id":"ChIJLTex1jQShEgR5UJ2DNc6N9s",
         "types":[
            "street_address"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
json_decode($response->results->geometry->location->lat)
```

But it returns 'trying to access the property of a non-object'.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: json_decode($response)->results->geometry->location->lat ?

Comment: Returns the same error - `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var_dump(json_decode($response)->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);
```

Comment: Works perfectly! `results[0]`, how could I let that slip my attention. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Either pass true as the second parameter to json_decode function and use the array notation:

```
$obj = json_decode($json_string2, true);
foreach ($obj['geometry'] as $key => $value) {
    $lat = $value['location']['lat'];
    $long   = $value['location']['lng'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`$jsonArray = json_decode($response,true);`

It's just, first you got to convert whole json string into array or object with `json_decode` function, then work with structure.

Comment: Even if I do this - `$jsonArray = json_decode($response,true); dd($jsonArray->results);` it still returns the `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: Did you readen my answer? This code `$jsonArray = json_decode($response,true);` returns an ARRAY, not object. So acces it's field with `dd($jsonArray['results']);`